# Nifi: How to sync two directories in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to  write my response  flowfiles in one  directory than  get  data  from it  change it and then  put it  inside other  dierctory  i want to  make this  two  direcotry sync(i mean that  whenever i delet, or  change  flowfile in one  directory  it  should  change  in other  directories  too ) I have  ore  than 10000  flowfiles  so chechlist  wouldn't be  good  solution. Can  you reccomend me:

1. any  contreoller  service  which  can help me make this?
2. any better  way  i can make  this  task  without controller  service

Comment: [rsync tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Comment: can i use rsync inside  nifi i mean  can i make   workflow  so that  rsync  catch changes inside  hdfs  directories?

Comment: or can  i  implement it in  custom processor  i  mean if  i write  custom proceeosor  can i  implement rsync  for  local  directories?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `ListFile`, `FetchFile`, and `PutFile` processors to detect individual file write changes within a file system directory and copy their contents to another directory. This will *not* detect file *deletions* however, so I believe a better solution is to use `rsync` within an `ExecuteProcess` processor.

To the best of my knowledge, `rsync` does not work on HDFS file systems, so in that case I would recommend using a tool like [Helix](http://helix.apache.org/0.7.0-incubating-docs/recipes/rsync_replicated_file_store.html) or [DistCp](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html)  (I have not evaluated these tools in particular). You can either invoke them from the "command line" via `ExecuteProcess` or wrapping a client library in an `ExecuteScript` or custom processor.